# How to change many buttons class with one id on click to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'll display friend requests by looping where have button to accept friend request with one id.

HTML code:

```
foreach($friendRequests as $request) {
    <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
      {{$request['userName']}} send to you friend request. 
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning pull-right" value="{{ $request->senderId }}" id="accept">Accept</button>
    </div>  
}
```

Here on looping will be displayed 6 friend requests with accept buttons.

Javascript code:

```
var accept = document.querySelector('#accept');

$(accept).on('click', function() {
    if(accept.classList.contains("btn-warning") == true) {
        accept.classList.remove("btn-warning");
        accept.classList.add("btn-success");
    } else if (accept.classList.contains("btn-success") == true) {
        accept.classList.remove("btn-success");
        accept.classList.add("btn-warning");
    }
});
```

When I click to first friend request all works good but other buttons not works. How can I use my code correctly to each buttons?

Comment: querySelector() only finds first matching selector in page and add to that ID's must be unique in a page. Use class instead.

Comment: The `id` attribute specifies a `unique` id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document). You should use `class` attribute instead of ID. A class name can be used by multiple elements.

Comment: How I must rewrite my javascript code? What I must use instead `querySelector()`? Where I can use `id` for change clicked button class or how I can detect clicked button? @charlietfl

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute  Note that by using and ID, it (most often) gets the FIRST element with that id and not an array of objects as you expect https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H93.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use class because ids are for uniqueness. And you have jquery included why not use it.

```
$(document).on('click','.accept', function(){
    if(this.classList.contains("btn-warning") == true) {
        this.classList.remove("btn-warning");
        this.classList.add("btn-success");
    } else if (this.classList.contains("btn-success") == true) {
        this.classList.remove("btn-success");
        this.classList.add("btn-warning");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

ID's should be unique. No two elements should have the same ID.

> `var accept = document.querySelector('#accept');`

The `querySelector` only returns the first element it finds, what you want to use is `document.querySelectorAll('.accept-button');`